# Rails 4: link_to submit form using ajax, how to imitate post request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, put, link-to

In my rails app I want the use to be able to hide anything on their wall by doing an ajax request and adding the item id to the database.

Here is the request I want to imitate the following:

```
Started POST "/report_fixed_vulns" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-19 21:28:45 +0100
Processing by ReportFixedVulnsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "report_fixed_vuln"=>{"report_id"=>"2", "vuln_id"=>"2", "user_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create Report fixed vuln"}
```

I tried using the following code to do this.

```
<%= button_to 'Submit', report_fixed_vuln_path(:report_fixed_vuln => {:report_id => @report_id, :vuln_id => plugin.first.id, :user_id => current_user.id}), :remote => true, :method => :put %>
```

However this generates a different request:

```
Started PUT "/report_fixed_vulns/323?report_fixed_vuln%5Breport_id%5D=323&report_fixed_vuln%5Buser_id%5D=1&report_fixed_vuln%5Bvuln_id%5D=443" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-19 21:32:51 +0100
Processing by ReportFixedVulnsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "report_fixed_vuln"=>{"report_id"=>"323", "user_id"=>"1", "vuln_id"=>"443"}, "id"=>"323"}
```

Here is my question: How to I imitate the first request using `button_to` (the parameters don't need to be entered -- they're already there on the page)

Comment: The `method: :put` for this Path will trigger the update action, whereas `method: :post` will call the create action of the Controller. What do you want to do with this Submit button_to? Do you want a button to create quickly a record with default parameters?

Comment: yes I want it to create a record with default parameters

Comment: when i tried 'method: :post' it gives me `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/report_fixed_vulns/323"):` Not sure what to do

Comment: Try using `new_report_fixed_vuln_path` with the same arguments you used before

Comment: got `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/report_fixed_vulns/new"):`

Comment: I went to `/report_fixed_vulns/new` and it exists

Comment: Ah my bad, try `report_fixed_vulns_path` (plural) with method: :post

Comment: `undefined method 'new_report_fixed_vulns_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003b5db20>:0x000000049e67f0>`

Comment: Without the new: `button_to 'Submit', report_fixed_vulns_path(:report_fixed_vuln => {:report_id => @report_id, :vuln_id => plugin.first.id, :user_id => current_user.id}), :remote => true, :method => :post` (see the plural on `report_fixed_vulns_path`)

Comment: got it! yeah it seems to work now :D

Comment: Submit this as answer and I will accept!! :D thank you so much!

Comment: quick question: is it possible to hide the button once it has been clicked?

Comment: I updated my answer with a way to hide the button once it has been clicked ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to this routing guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

It says the helper for the create method is:

```
POST    /admin/posts    create  admin_posts_path
```

So you should use the helper `report_fixed_vulns_path` (note the plural) with the same arguments but with `method: :post` (PUT is for update), **in your case**:

```
<%= button_to 'Submit', report_fixed_vulns_path(:blabla => hash), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

---

If you want to hide the button right after you clicked on it, you can add an onclick event: (jQuery)

```
<%= button_to 'Submit', report_fixed_vulns_path(:blabla => hash), :remote => true, :method => :post, :onclick => '$(this).hide();' %>
```